# Drivers - Is it possible to make the frame number of one clip dependent of the frame number of another?

Tags: video-sequence-editor, drivers, graph-editor

My goal is to play a video clip scene as if I was scratching on the time line like a DJ on his LPs forth and back.

I thought, maybe it is possible to make the frame number of this clip dependent from the frame number of another clip, so that I could control the first clip with an expression like:

```
frame_clip1 = 100 + 30*sin(frame_clip2)
```

If it worked, one clip would go from frame one to the last frame, the usual way, and the other clip would oscillate back and forth through time.